# Prisma: Error: P1017 Server has closed the connection

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a prisma 2 project with nodejs server all things was working pefectly, and when I upgraded prisma from 2 to "3.0.2" version the `prisma db push` command no longer work and it throws this error:

```
Error: P1017
Server has closed the connection.
```

I am sure that the postgres database works because all queries and mutations requests are work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `prisma db pull` then `prisma db push` and it works perfectly

I think that error was a mistake in schema.prisma file when I pull it from the database I think this correct the mistakes in the file

Comment: This is really weird, but worked